# NullPointer Exception when running testcases as groups from xml file

Tags: selenium-webdriver, intellij-idea, selenium-chromedriver, testng, testng.xml

I am new in selenium. I tried to run two classes from an XML file. I grouped tests in these two classes. But when I add  tag in XML file it gives a nullpointer exception. But when I run it with , it works fine.

xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd">
<suite name="Annotation running">

    <test name="Annotation Test Runner With Group!" >
        <groups>
            <run>
                <include name="smoke"/>
            </run>
        </groups>
        <classes>
            <class name="DemoPractise.Annotation"/>
            <class name="DemoPractise.annotation2"/>

        </classes>
    </test>

</suite>
```

Erro Log

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DemoPractise.Annotation.test2_BtsListBox(Annotation.java:31)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)


java.lang.NullPointerException
    at DemoPractise.annotation2.test4_JQueryListBox(annotation2.java:32)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:139)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:664)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:227)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:50)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:957)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:200)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:148)
    at org.testng.internal.invokers.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1541)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:848)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:621)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:443)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:437)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:397)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:336)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:95)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1280)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1200)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1114)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1082)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.IDEARemoteTestNG.run(IDEARemoteTestNG.java:66)
    at com.intellij.rt.testng.RemoteTestNGStarter.main(RemoteTestNGStarter.java:105)


===============================================
Annotation running
Total tests run: 2, Passes: 0, Failures: 2, Skips: 0
===============================================


Process finished with exit code 0
```

I tried setuping the driver in @BeforeMethod. But it isn't inializing when using  tag to name the groups in xml file.

Answer (score 0):

The NullPointerException you are encountering in your test class is likely due to the way you have initialized the WebDriver instance and the test methods in your class. The problem is that the WebDriver instance is being initialized outside of any test method, causing it to be null when the test methods are executed.
To fix this issue, you should initialize the WebDriver instance within each test method or using TestNG's @BeforeMethod annotation.

```
WebDriver driver;

    @BeforeSuite
    public void browserSetup() {
        WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup(); // You should setup WebDriverManager for Chrome
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.manage().window().maximize();
    }

    @Test(groups = "original")
    public void test1_BtsDatePicker() {
        driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-playground/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Bootstrap Date Picker")).click();
    }

    @Test(groups = {"regression", "smoke"})
    public void test2_BtsListBox() {
        driver.get("https://www.lambdatest.com/selenium-playground/");
        driver.findElement(By.linkText("Bootstrap List Box")).click();
    }

    @AfterSuite
    public void tearDown() {
        if (driver != null) {
            driver.quit(); // Use quit to close the browser and release resources
        }
    }
```

Comment: I also tried with @BeforeMethod annotation, but the result is the same! Although, it works if I initialize a webdriver instance in each test method. But I want to create a web driver instance once and use it for all other test methods. And the above code works when I run the test methods with the '<exclude>' tag in the XML file. Problems only happen when I use the '<include>' tag.

Comment: So declare the webDriver as static.

Comment: My question is the code works fine but when it group ran from XML using the 'exclude' tag! Why it is not running with the 'include' tag?And why the nullpointer exception for include tag?

Answer (score 0):

This problem happened because I didn't add the @BeforeSuite  and @AfterSuite methods to a group and add them to the XML file. I thought these two methods would run whether I included them in the XML file or not! With only 'exclude,' it runs because it runs all the techniques except the methods in the provided group.